# import text file containing Unicode in Excel 2010 with VBA

Tags: vba, excel-2013

A strange case here. This is VBA code that was auto-generated with "Record macro" after importing a text file containing Unicode characters in an Excel 2013:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Folder1\Sampletxtfile.txt", _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "Sampletxtfile"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 65001
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

The problem is: if I use this code and run it on my own it gives an error ("Invalid procedure call or argument") on line:
.Command type=0
Any help correcting this please? And shouldn't autogenerated code be useful precisely because it indicates correct syntax? I usually use it for this...

Comment: Have you tried removing .Command line

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN entry regarding QueryTable.CommandType Property
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840602(v=office.15).aspx

> You can set the CommandType property only if the value of the QueryType property for the query table or PivotTable cache is xlOLEDBQuery.

You're not making an OLEDB query so the QueryType is something else. Since it's something else, then you can't set the CommandType, so just remove it.